# Outlook for Mac 2011 - how to delete buggy email in outbox that crashes Outlook

Tags: email, ms-office, crash

I have an email in my Outbox that continually crashes Outlook for Mac 2011 with a "rebuild database" error message. Rebuilding the database took days and never completed. If I start Outlook in safe mode (holding the shift key when loading), I can get into Outlook but the moment I hit Send/Receive or switch to the Outbox folder (where the culprit email is sitting), I immediately get the "rebuild database" error message and can either Rebuild or Cancel, the latter exits Outlook.

Is there a way to empty the Outbox folder through the file system without click on the folder in Outlook? Any other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you delete the message in the outbox from webmail?  If it is not in webmail then it's on the outlook end of things.  If that is the case I would remove the entire profile in outlook and re-enter the e-mail accounts and let it build all over again rather than trying to just rebuild the database.